# Exclude node_modules form typescript compile via gulp-typescript

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-typescript

I'm trying to run a gulp task to compile my typescript but keep on getting errors related to dependencies.

```
/content/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts(12,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
/content/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts(13,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
```

I am trying to omit the node_modules directory so that it will only notify me of problems in my code. my files are as follows:

gulpfile.js

```
var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json');
gulp.task('ts', function () {
    return gulp.src([aemPaths.jcrRoot + '**/*.ts'])
        .pipe(tsProject())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(aemPaths.jcrRoot));
});
```

I've also tried

```
gulp.task('ts', function () {
    return gulp.src([aemPaths.jcrRoot + '**/*.ts','!node_modules/**/*'])
        .pipe(tsProject())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(aemPaths.jcrRoot));
});
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

I've done many searches but can't seem to find a way to omit this with gulp-typescript. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need exlude node_modules directory into gulp, just add typings es6-collections and es6-promise into gulp.src array

Comment: forgive me if I am miss understanding as this is all very new to me. I went ahead and installed the following: `npm install --save-dev es6-promise es6-collections` but still get the same typescript errors on compile.

Comment: @kisonay 

Use 'npm install typings' command. 

Install actual typings: 
'typings install es6-collections';
'typings install es6-promise';

then, into directory typings you will find index.d.ts. You need include this file inot your gulp.src